# init method and "Object with a +0 retain count returned to caller where a +1 (owning) retain count is expected" - false positive?

Tags: objective-c, clang-static-analyzer

First of all:
I understand, why this warning is existing, I just can't explain myself, why it is triggered under these circumstances.
The official Cocoa memory management policy is as following:
"You own any object you create
You create an object using a method whose name begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy” (for example, alloc, newObject, or mutableCopy).

You can take ownership of an object using retain"

I know have code like this:

```
- (id) foo
{
    // do something
    return self;
}

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    return [self foo]; // clang static analyzer is complaining about returning an object with a +0 retain count here, although a +1 would be expected
}
```

Afaik this is a false positive from clang, isn't it?
I mean, the only methods, which increase the retain-count, are "retain" and all methods, whose names begin with "alloc", "new", "copy", or "mutableCopy", so "init" is not increasing the retain-count, but relays on the caller, to pass in the return-value of the class' "alloc"-method, so actually "init" is expected to return a +0 retain count, not a +1 one, isn't it? It just returns the object with the same retain count, with which it has been passed in.
Now calling "foo" on that object also does not change the retain count, so this code should be perfectly legal and in fact it works just fine and the retain count is correct all over the whole life time of the program, only the static analyzer is complaining.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method name `foo` by convention means that it returns an object that the caller does not own.

`alloc`-`init***` combinations return an object that the caller owns.

Looks like the analyzer can't or doesn't bother to look inside `foo` to see what it's actually doing, and does not know that the returned value is the same object as the already owned `self`.

It is not a false positive. If a subclass, or a dynamically loaded category override foo to return something else:

```
- (id) foo; {
    return [NSNumber numberWithInt:666];
}
```

then you will have a leak of `self` and an over-release of `NSNumber` object.

Comment: Afaik foo by convention just means, that it does not change the retain count, same like init. Where does the convention state anything about having to return an autoreleased object there?

Comment: @Kaiserludi It specifies whether you own an object or not. You're replacing an object that you own with another that you don't, which is clearly a mistake in all cases except when they are the same object, and because of dynamic code loading, you can't be sure that will always be the case. Seems completely reasonable behavior to me.

Comment: @Kaiserludi In fact, there's two problems here: one, you are returning the result of a method marked (by convention) as returning a non-owned object (i.e. return [self foo]). That's the error the compiler's complaining about. Two, you are returning something other than self from an init method, without releasing self (i.e. you're leaking self). The way foo is written, these two errors (one overrelease and one leak) happen to cancel each other out.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is a false-positive, but this is a bad practice to use when designing a class.
Instead, you should call foo, then return self, like so:

```
-(id) init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        [self foo];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Please see hamstergene's answer for how this is not a false positive.

Comment: @jfortmann from my understanding of the OP, the selector in question was not defined in the headers, thus, no subclass would know to override it.

Comment: If a subclass might override it in this implementation is not relevant for the compiler. The _only_ thing that's relevant is the naming, which, for -foo, says 'this method returns a value not owned by the caller'.